# How to install openssh-server, tcsh, autofs and ypbind on Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop version?

Tags: openssh

How to install openssh-server, tcsh, autofs and ypbind on Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop version?
I'd like to modify the source.list to use apt-get for similar packages.
They are all in trusty/main or trusty/universe...
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forget to execute "apt-get update" after install OS and before install those packages.
It's resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The packages `openssh-server`, `tcsh`,  and `autofs` are available from the official package sources so you can just install them. `ypbind` is in the package `nis` which is available by default, too.